# Is there a difference between $n \to \infty$ and $n \uparrow \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given a series $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers, I am unsure about the difference between
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\lim_{n \uparrow \infty} x_n.
$$
I think I read somewhere that the latter only states convergence for *increasing* sequences $x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le \dots$
If that is true, could you help me out with an example of a series for which $\lim_{n \uparrow \infty} x_n$ exists, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of limit notation is needed for limits that are not on the boundaries of domains.

For example: $\lim_{x \uparrow 0}\frac 1x=-\infty$ is the limit to zero from the negative direction and $\lim_{x \downarrow 0}\frac 1x = \infty$ is the limit to zero from the positive direction. The distinction makes sense as $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1x$ is ambiguous and should not be used as it is not clear which limit is meant. Sometimes, when we know that the limit will not depend on the direction from which we approach the limit point $x_0$, we tend to simply write $\lim_{x \to x_0}$.

As $n \to \infty$, assuming $n \in \mathbb{R}$, only allows approach from one direction it is not necessary to explicitly write $n\uparrow \infty$.

Comment: Worth pointing out the other common notation for this, $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}$, though I think arrow form is much better!

Comment: +1: I wish I'd thought to point out where the notations differed. Even though the OP didn't ask for that exactly, it's clear in retrospect that he wanted to know that. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Both indicate the limit of a sequence $x_n$ as $n$ increases without bound. They are different ways of denoting exactly the same thing.